# Multiplying the answer to a form and having it show up in the total

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, multiplication

Hey guys i'm having an issue with auto filling the final form on my order page. I have a drop down menu that makes you select a value for example 1000. I want my total form at the bottom to automatically multiple what ever number they pick (1000) by .12 and have it show up as 120 in the total form at the bottom. 
 here is what I have,

```
    <td><label for="CAT_Custom_489400">Number of orders (.12 cents per) <span class="req">*</span></label><br />
                <select name="CAT_Custom_489400" id="CAT_Custom_489400" class="cat_dropdown">
                <option value=" ">-- Please select --</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="3000">3000</option>
                <option value="4000">4000</option>
                <option value="5000">5000</option>
                <option value="10000">10000</option>
                <option value="15000">15000</option>
                <option value="20000">20000</option>
                <option value="25000">25000</option>
                <option value="30000">30000</option>
                <option value="40000">40000</option>
                <option value="50000">50000</option>
                </select></td>
then at the bottom is the amount total form,
 <td><label for="Amount">Amount <span class="req">*</span> <span id="constraint-300-label"></span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="Amount" id="Amount" class="cat_textbox" /></td>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show some source code? That will make it more likely that we can help identify your problem since it is likely somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply attach a function to the onchange event. (Make sure to change the value to a float using parseFloat(), because it will give you a string)

```
my_func = function(x) {
    new_value = parseFloat(x) * .12; 
    Amount.value= new_value;
}
<select onchange="my_func(this.value);">
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
    <option value="4000">4000</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="Amount" id="Amount" class="cat_textbox" />
```

working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/f6zGE/